# Extracting blobs from PostgreSQL using Python - "pause" at the beginning

Tags: python, postgresql, blob, psycopg2

I want to extract blobs from rows, inside individual files - and am using Python code that looks like this:

```
connDB = psycopg2.connect(
    database=strDbName, user=strUser, password=strPass,
    host=strHost, port=strPort)
cur = connDB.cursor()
cmd = """
select id || '.pdf' as filename, blobColumn as binaryData
from someTable
"""
cur.execute(cmd)
while True:
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None: break
    print "Generating:", row[0]
    open(row[0], 'w').write(row[1][:])
```

This works fine, but when the table contains more than e.g. 500 rows, I start noticing a delay when starting the script - as if the database is "taking a picture" up-front, and then "feeding" me this picture. The end result is that there's no output for some time, and then the blobs start pouring out.

If my hunch is correct:

- I'd very much like to avoid this "picture" - because blobs are big, and so will the "picture", straining the DB and delaying my output for no reason.
- An alternative I am contemplating is reading all IDs of the rows up-front, adding them into a Python array, and then looping over that array, executing one `select blobColumn where id=...` per iteration. Shouldn't this be better?

Thanks for any hints - and even though this is about Python, PostgreSQL and psycopg2, I'd be interested to hear whether this is DB-engine specific, whether I am missing some better use of the psycopg2 API, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `named cursor`. It defaults in `psycopg2` to 2000, but since you have noticed a threshold around 500, try setting it much lower than that, say 100 or 200. You do this simply by providing a **name** parameter to the cursor constructor.

The `named cursor` will allow `psycopg2` to automatically query in batches by setting up a server-side `cursor` for you. On the `Python` side, you simply iterate as usual, and it will fetch more from the server when necessary.

Also, it may be instructive to look at the `query plan` for the larger-sized tables to see how they differ from the smaller ones.

If you use the `named cursor`, after you run the `execute`, you simply `iterate` instead of calling `fetchone` or similar.

i.e.

```
for row in cur:
    # do stuff here
```

Comment: Perfect suggestion, worked like a charm. All I had to do was switch to "cur = connDB.cursor(name='test')" and then "cur.itersize=10" - the blobs then started appearing instantly. Thanks!